# Final Cut Pro X won't accept similar files

Tags: ffmpeg, final-cut-pro-x, ffprobe

I have two files that I want to import into Final Cut Pro X. They are both clips pulled from the same source file using the same commands. I am using a generated script to extract dozens of clips at a time so they are identical other than the output filename. This is the command I am running to create them:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:02:33 -to 00:02:37 -i c66d0aaedc7848f39066faa244542eac.mkv \
    -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 -vendor apl0 -bits_per_mb 8000 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le \
    -map_chapters -1 -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 \
    -metadata:s:a:0 title="Stereo" cinderella33-extra.mov
```

They seem almost identical when I check them with `mediainfo` and `ffprobe`. Here are the outputs from those.

cinderalla3.mov:

```
General
Complete name                            : cinderella3.mov
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : QuickTime
Codec ID                                 : qt   0000.02 (qt  )
File size                                : 232 MiB
Duration                                 : 6 s 48 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 322 Mb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf59.16.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : ProRes
Format version                           : Version 0
Format profile                           : 422 HQ
Codec ID                                 : apch
Duration                                 : 6 s 48 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 322 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1 456 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:2
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 8.545
Stream size                              : 232 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : Apple
Language                                 : English

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 6 s 0 ms
Source duration                          : 6 s 21 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 93.5 KiB (0%)
Source stream size                       : 94.0 KiB (0%)
Title                                    : Stereo
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1

ffprobe version 5.0 Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.27.3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.0-with-options --enable-shared --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-demuxer=dash --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-htmlpages --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'cinderella3.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf59.16.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 322280 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: prores (HQ) (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(tv, progressive), 1456x1080, 322160 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 182:135, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : FFMP
      encoder         : Lavc59.18.100 prores_ks
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

cinderella191.mov:

```
General
Complete name                            : cinderella191.mov
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : QuickTime
Codec ID                                 : qt   0000.02 (qt  )
File size                                : 137 MiB
Duration                                 : 5 s 5 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 230 Mb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf59.16.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : ProRes
Format version                           : Version 0
Format profile                           : 422 HQ
Codec ID                                 : apch
Duration                                 : 5 s 5 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 230 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1 456 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:2
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 6.106
Stream size                              : 137 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : Apple
Language                                 : English

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 5 s 0 ms
Source duration                          : 5 s 21 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 129 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 78.4 KiB (0%)
Source stream size                       : 78.9 KiB (0%)
Title                                    : Stereo
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1

ffprobe version 5.0 Copyright (c) 2007-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.27.3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.0-with-options --enable-shared --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-demuxer=dash --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-htmlpages --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'cinderella191.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf59.16.100
  Duration: 00:00:05.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 230352 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: prores (HQ) (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(tv, progressive), 1456x1080, 230215 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 182:135, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : FFMP
      encoder         : Lavc59.18.100 prores_ks
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

and here's the result when I `diff` the two outputs

```
2c2
< Complete name                            : cinderella3.mov
---
> Complete name                            : cinderella191.mov
6,7c6,7
< File size                                : 232 MiB
< Duration                                 : 6 s 48 ms
---
> File size                                : 137 MiB
> Duration                                 : 5 s 5 ms
9c9
< Overall bit rate                         : 322 Mb/s
---
> Overall bit rate                         : 230 Mb/s
18c18
< Duration                                 : 6 s 48 ms
---
> Duration                                 : 5 s 5 ms
20c20
< Bit rate                                 : 322 Mb/s
---
> Bit rate                                 : 230 Mb/s
29,30c29,30
< Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 8.545
< Stream size                              : 232 MiB (100%)
---
> Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 6.106
> Stream size                              : 137 MiB (100%)
39,40c39,40
< Duration                                 : 6 s 0 ms
< Source duration                          : 6 s 21 ms
---
> Duration                                 : 5 s 0 ms
> Source duration                          : 5 s 21 ms
42c42
< Bit rate                                 : 128 kb/s
---
> Bit rate                                 : 129 kb/s
48,49c48,49
< Stream size                              : 93.5 KiB (0%)
< Source stream size                       : 94.0 KiB (0%)
---
> Stream size                              : 78.4 KiB (0%)
> Source stream size                       : 78.9 KiB (0%)
66c66
< Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'cinderella3.mov':
---
> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'cinderella191.mov':
72,73c72,73
<   Duration: 00:00:06.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 322280 kb/s
<   Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: prores (HQ) (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(tv, progressive), 1456x1080, 322160 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 182:135, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn (default)
---
>   Duration: 00:00:05.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 230352 kb/s
>   Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: prores (HQ) (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(tv, progressive), 1456x1080, 230215 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 182:135, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn (default)
78c78
<   Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
---
>   Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
```

Why will FCPX import `cinderella191.mov` but won't take `cinderella3.mov`?

Answer (score 0):

I moved all the files I'm trying to import to a different directory and FCPX was willing to import all of them. Obviously, I don't know the specifics about why it wouldn't import them but here's my best guess:

Earlier I had tried to import a version of those files that were all blocked using the import option. Those were rejected because it didn't like the audio portion of the videos. The only difference between that first set of files and similar files that FCPX liked was they were missing a field called `Title` that was set to `Stereo` so I added `-metadata:s:a:0 title="Stereo"` to the `ffmpeg` parameters.

That created the set of files that prompted this question. Going back to the import screen, I noticed that the files FCPX didn't like were all on the first page of the file list, and subsequently all the files it would accept were after the first page. Instinct had me wonder if FCPX had cached the file information for that first page of the file list. So when I moved the files to a different subdirectory, I forced FCPX to reprocess the file check.

That fixed it. Don't know that I'm 100% right about the cause but it fixed the issue so I'm good.